# To get refreshtoken, accesstoken in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to generate credentials (AccessToken, RefreshToken) in Microsoft Graph API. Successfully generated AccessToken by following [this Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-postman). But I am struggling with the way to get a refresh token.

Steps:

- *App Registration is done in Azure Active Directory.*

  [image: App Registration]
- *Client Secret also got*

  [image: Client Secret]
- *List of API Permission Given*

  [image: API Permission]

As per [this Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user), I followed the remaining steps to generate credentials.

- *Below mentioned Authorization Request pasted in google URL and got code value as well.*

**Request**:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
  ?client_id=14edf196-xxxxxx
  &response_type=code
  &redirect_uri=https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/browser-callback 
  &response_mode=query
  &scope=offline_access%20Mail.Read%20Mail.ReadBasic%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Mail.Read.Shared%20Mail.ReadWrite.Shared%20Mail.Send%20Mail.Send.Shared%20MailboxSettings.Read%20MailboxSettings.ReadWrite%20IMAP.AccessAsUser.All%20POP.AccessAsUser.All%20SMTP.Send%20Files.Read%20Files.Read.All%20Files.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.All%20Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder%20Files.Read.Selected%20Files.ReadWrite.Selected%20User.Read%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All%20User.Read.All%20User.ReadWrite.All%20User.Invite.All%20User.Export.All%20User.ManageIdentities.All
  &state=12345
```

**Code value:**

```
0.ASUAYH3m5fSttECIPDUdwv7vTpbx7RSNwIhCtEISG2GkwQwlAMQ.AQABAAIAAADxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

- Next step is to get AccessToken, for this POST request made in Postman which gives AccessToken in Response

  [image: AccessToken Generation]

  Note: When i remove scope in above request, accesstoken received, otherwise i got ERROR Respose like

  > "error: invalid_grant Description:AADSTS70008: The provided authorization code or refresh token has expired due to inactivity. Send a new interactive authorization request for this user and resource.\r\nTrace ID: 98e82735-4764-496a-881b-9b78faf3f000\r\nCorrelation ID: 3d4a78b2-5a26-47af-ae14-cbb82c12a9ae\r\nTimestamp: 2021-06-14 12:57:01Z"

As per OAuth2.0, i hope no need to pass scope while generating accesstoken.

**Response**:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "email openid profile https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.All https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.Read.Selected https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.All https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder https://graph.microsoft.com/Files.ReadWrite.Selected https://graph.microsoft.com/IMAP.AccessAsUser.All https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read.Shared https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadBasic https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite.Shared https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send.Shared https://graph.microsoft.com/MailboxSettings.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/MailboxSettings.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All https://graph.microsoft.com/SMTP.Send https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Export.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Invite.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ManageIdentities.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadBasic.All https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJubxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

If you seen in above json response comes from postman, refresh token is missing.

This refresh token is required while integrating MS Outlook operation in WSO2 EI by following [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Outlook+Mail+Operations)

Kindly help me to get this. or what is the step that i missed?

Comment: Hi @Marc LaFleur,

Thanks for editing. Could you please provide me a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created another App and given limited set of scopes like email Mail.Read User.Read profile openid which has been passed to both Authorize and token endpoint. Now i can get access token, refresh token and id token in response.

[image: Token Request]

Response:

```
    {
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "email Mail.Read User.Read profile openid",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6ImZWTnhDbVBlZkRMd3g3eG5PbDZxNE5jWkNCV3lETGZJR3FoamU5QktGMDQiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIxxxx",
    "refresh_token": "0.AXEAYH3m5fSttECIPDUdwv7vThdQk6TogBNEp2J4CzLY-WhxANs.AgABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7Wevxxxxx",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCHJPRFhFS9.eyJhdWQiOiJhNDkzxxxxxxx"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`offline_access` is not always added until we add `offline_access` in the scope explicitly. It provides us with a refresh token after that.

Answer (score -1):

Please use scope as - '**https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access**'

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Shweta,
Thank you for your suggestion.
if we have multiple scope all needs to be prefixed with "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" separated by space? eg. https://graph.microsoft.com/.default offline_access https://graph.microsoft.com/.default mail.read

Comment: Scopes can be either static (using /.default) or dynamic.  If you need application permissions, you must use /.default to request the statically configured list of permissions.  When you used a static (/.default) value, it will function like the v1.0 admin consent endpoint and request consent for all scopes found in the required permissions for the app. For dynamic, you can pass multiple permissions like mail.read offline_access (space separated) and so on.

Comment: `offline_access` is always added, even if it wasn't explicitly requested.